# simple question cp (command)

Tags: cp

my problem is ''**cp**'' command 
I can't understand why I can't copy a simple text file
for example:
I have on the desktop two files **"fis1"** and **"fis2"**
and in **"fis1"** I have ***"perfect***" (text file)
*and I want to copy the* **"perfect"** file to **"fis2"** [which is still on the desktop]
and any attempt with "cp" does not work

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? Which release? Read `man cp`, or even `cp --help`. Also Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/1208547/edit your Question and show us what you've tried, and what the errors were. Also `ls -lRA fis1 fis2`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all let's clarify something: fis1 and fis2 are folders and not files? If yes, you must first find out where you are located (in wich directory) if you are using the terminal.
The command is: pwd

if, like me you are located in the home directory (which ends with this sign ~$ ) then you have to relocate in the Desktop directory.
You do this by writing command:
cd Desktop

After that you can use this command to copy the file:
cp fis1/perfect fis2/

I hope I helped you.